# Scala not recognizing type after pimping JSoup

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm trying to do some web scraping in Scala, and is currently using [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/). Now I found that the iterator is not working in Scala, so I did some pimpin' and wrote an iterator myself. It looks like this:

```
object Pimp {

  implicit class PimpElements(es: Elements) extends Iterable[Element] {
    def iterator = new Iterator[Element] {
      var currentElem = 0

      def hasNext = currentElem < size

      def next(): Element = {
        currentElem += 1
        es.get(currentElem - 1)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, the code that does not work, because intelliJ or Scala does not recognize my variable `cider` to be of type `Element` I guess:

```
for (cider <- ciders; if cider.getElementsByClass("info").text() != "") {
      ciderArray += Drink(DrinkType.CIDER, cider)
}
```

But why not? My `next()` method returns `es.get(i)` which supposedly should be an `Element` and works in the code below:

```
for (i <- 0 to ciders.size() - 1; if ciders.get(i).getElementsByClass("info").text() != "") {
      ciderArray += Drink(DrinkType.CIDER, ciders.get(i))
}
```

Isn't this code basically doing the same as the iterator, but gets recognized for some reason? The type of `cider` is, according to intelliJ, `Any` and not `Element`.

Comment: Does it compile using sbt? Sometimes IntelliJ falsely marks errors when it can't figure out the type.

Comment: It still doesn't compile normally? What versions of Scala, Java and JSoup? and Idea? though I can't try the IDE just now.

Answer (score 1):

The `for` comprehension is translated to `c.withFilter(p).foreach(f)`.

Possibly you expected it to call `iterator`.

This question is interesting because these encodings can result in more inferred type parameters or other effects.

I see `Elements` is an `ArrayList`.

`TraversableLike.withFilter` does turn out to be different from `Iterator.withFilter`.

Your example works, after fixing the call to `size` (which stackoverflows). It also works with Java types for Elements and Element.

```
object Test extends App {

  case class Element(value: String)

  type Elements = java.util.ArrayList[Element]

  implicit class PimpElements(es: Elements) extends Iterable[Element] {
    def iterator = new Iterator[Element] {
      var currentElem = 0

      def hasNext = currentElem < es.size

      def next(): Element = {
        currentElem += 1
        es.get(currentElem - 1)
      }
    }
  }

  val vs = new java.util.ArrayList[Element]
  vs.add(new Element("hi"))
  vs.add(new Element("bye"))

  for (v <- vs if v.value.startsWith("h")) println(v)
}
```

But it will also work this way:

```
object Test extends App {

  implicit class PimpElements(es: Elements) extends Iterator[Element] {
    var currentElem = 0 

    def hasNext = currentElem < es.size

    def next(): Element = { 
      currentElem += 1 
      es.get(currentElem - 1)
    } 
  }

  val vs = new Elements
  vs.add(new Element("hi"))
  vs.add(new Element("bye"))

  for (v <- vs if v.value.startsWith("h")) println(v)
}
```

The `Traversable` tracks its representation as a type parameter, which might make for type inference issues. Both classes incur a wrapper for filtering. But the `Iterator` doesn't override `foreach` when filtering, so it saves the last unfiltered element on `hasNext` for the call to `next`. Possibly, the `Traversable.foreach` is more efficient.

Comment: I'm very new to Scala so I'm not 100 % sure what you mean. Are you saying that Scala's `for`-loop does not call my `iterator`-method? I fixed the `es.size` error, but that does not make it worked any more than before :/

Comment: It directly calls `foreach`; the "if guard" translates to `withFilter`. How your iterator is called is (surprisingly) different for the two examples of supplying an `Iterable` or an `Iterator`.